# Exclude sub springboot project in gradle during bootrun task

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a multilevel spring boot project. I created a subproject which is also another spring boot project. When i run bootrun task in the gradle of parent project it started executing the child bootrun. How to exclude the child bootrun from parent bootrun?

```
     +--- Project ':services:A'
     +--- Project ':services:B'
     +--- Project ':services:C'
     |    +--- Project ':services:C:subproject'
     |    |    \--- Project ':services:C:subproject:D'
    

where A,B,C and D are spring boot project.. subproject is directory name
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If i do gradle bootrun of service C, it automatically starting both C and D services.. I don't want to start D as part of gradle bootrun task of C